# Creating PDFs from Spreadsheet Need PDF URL to be returned to Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation

I have a spreadsheet that contains data, a doc that is acting as my template and the start of a script that creates a PDF using the spreadsheet & doc for each line of the data. This works great!

My next step and this is where I am struggling, is I need to put the URL/identifier (from google drive) of each created PDF (each PDF goes to the same folder) into my spreadsheet so that I can then create another script to email the recipient their document.

I've seen this done when using a form and triggers but as I am not actively collecting the data, I cannot figure out this next part.

Thanks,
Nate

```
/*This function takes the data from the Charitable Tax Receipt summary and passes one row at a time
to the createPDF function.
*/

    function createTaxRcptPDFs(){

    const DOCTEMPLATE = DriveApp.getFileById("ref");
    const TEMPFOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("ref1");
    const PDFFOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("ref2");
    const CURRENTSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST");
    const DATA = CURRENTSHEET.getRange(5,1,3,20).getDisplayValues(); //change 3 to formula when testing done

// this code block creates a data array to populate each PDF per (row)

    DATA.forEach(row => {

  const ACTIVECELL = row[20];
  createPDF(row[2],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[1],row[14],row[15],row[16],new Date(),row[1] + "_" + row[2],DOCTEMPLATE,TEMPFOLDER,PDFFOLDER);
  });

}


/* This function creates the PDF based on a Doc template and saves it to a specific folder
for future use.
*/

    function createPDF(fullName,street,city,state,postalCode,receiptNumber,donation,advantage,eligible,rcptDate,pdfName,DOCTEMPLATE,TEMPFOLDER,PDFFOLDER){

// constants/variables to use

    const TEMPFILE = DOCTEMPLATE.makeCopy(TEMPFOLDER);
    const TEMPDOCFILE = DocumentApp.openById(TEMPFILE.getId());

// array of values to create body from data

    const BODY = TEMPDOCFILE.getBody();
    BODY.replaceText("{fullName}", fullName);
    BODY.replaceText("{street}", street);
    BODY.replaceText("{city}", city);
    BODY.replaceText("{state}", state);
    BODY.replaceText("{postalCode}", postalCode);
    BODY.replaceText("{receiptNumber}", receiptNumber);
    BODY.replaceText("{donation}", donation);
    BODY.replaceText("{advantage}", advantage);
    BODY.replaceText("{eligible}", eligible);
    BODY.replaceText("{rcptDate}", rcptDate);
    TEMPDOCFILE.saveAndClose();

// create pdf and delete temp file

    const PDFBLOB = TEMPFILE.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    PDFFOLDER.createFile(PDFBLOB).setName(pdfName);
    TEMPFOLDER.removeFile(TEMPFILE);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

`setName(pdfName)` returns a File object for chaining, so you can use `getDownloadUrl()` right after.

```
var fileUrl = PDFFOLDER.createFile(PDFBLOB).setName(pdfName).getDownloadUrl();
```

### Reference:

[getDownloadUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl)

Comment: Thank you it was the line I needed!